# ¿Cómo vosear "Tú sabrás lo que haces"?

Tags: conjugación, argentina, voseo

El otro día invité por whatsapp a unos amigos argentinos a casa para celebrar la Nochevieja, y me dijeron que ya tenían planes, que habían quedado con otros argentinos "para vosear y yesear impunemente".

Yo quise responderle a modo de broma "tú sabrás lo que haces", pero voseando, así que le puse

> Vos sabrás lo que hacés

luego me surgió la duda de si debería haber sido

> Vos sabréis lo que hacés

¿Cuál es correcta según el voseo de Argentina?

Comment: Y a los que no os puedo invitar, os deseo un feliz y próspero 2020.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La forma correcta de "vosear" es:

> Vos sabrás lo que hacés

En Hispanoamérica, raramente se usa "sabréis", "veréis", etc.